# Is it possible to read system Decimal symbol using xslt

Tags: windows, xslt-1.0, system

Is it possible to know the current decimal symbol(number foirmat decimal - comma or dot) applied in the system using xslt ?

Comment: what you mean `comma or dot` in decimal? comma use for formating the number and . denote decimal points in any numbers. what is exact question. Please post with example for better sense.

Comment: @AmrendraKumar https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Countries_using_decimal_comma

Comment: I don't know of a way to get this information using purely XSLT 1.0. But if you're on Windows and using a Microsoft processor, you might be able to get it using an extension mechanism - see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb986124(v=msdn.10). Or simply send it as a parameter when initiating the transformation.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Exactly.  with xslt its a tough call. We have options in C#. What I think is possible is  I can embedd c# script within my xsl for the decimal seperator checking

Comment: Pass the character as a parameter to the transformation. In XSLT 3.0 one can access environment variables and this can be used as a convenient mechanism to store and retrieve any locale-dependent data from environment variables.